# How to position my plugin after cart in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Hi I have been amending and repurposing an old plugin for my own needs. I have manged to get the plugin how I want it but im struggling with the positioning of where the button created by the plugin is positioned in the single product page in Woocommerce. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction? I would like to display this button Underneath the add to cart button.

```
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array ( 'Request_Update', 'get_instance' ) );

    class Request_Update
    {
        /**
         * Internal variables prefix.
         *
         * @type string
         */
        private $prefix = 'RU';

    /**
     * Name for a field that is hidden per CSS and filled by spammers only.
     *
     * @type string
     */
    private $hidden_field = 'no_fill';

    /**
     * URL of the current page.
     *
     * @see __construct()
     * @type string
     */
    private $current_url = '';

    /**
     * nonce = number used once, unique identifier for request validation.
     *
     * @type string
     */
    private $nonce_name = 'RU_nonce';

    /**
     * On which post types do we want to show the form?
     *
     * @type array
     */
    private $post_types = array ( 'product' );

    /**
     * Creates a new instance. Called on 'after_setup_theme'.
     *
     * @see    __construct()
     * @return void
     */
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        static $instance = NULL;

        NULL === $instance and $instance = new self;

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Set actions, filters and basic variables, load language.
     *
     * @uses apply_filters() 'RU_button' as action name
     *      'RU_auto_add_button' to append the form automatically
     *      'RU_post_types' for supported post types (default: 'post')
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Use
        // do_action( 'RU_button' );
        // in your theme to show the button.
        add_action( $this->prefix . '_button', array ( $this, 'print_button' ) );

        // Use
        // add_filter( 'RU_auto_add_button', '__return_false' );
        // to turn automatic buttons off.
        if ( apply_filters( $this->prefix . '_auto_add_button', TRUE ) )
            add_filter( 'the_content', array ( $this, 'append_button' ), 50 );

        $this->current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        // Use
        // add_filter( 'RU_post_types', 'your_callback' );
        // to add more post types.
        $this->post_types  = apply_filters(
            $this->prefix . '_post_types',
            $this->post_types
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handler for the action 'RU_button'. Prints the button.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function print_button()
    {
        print $this->button_form();
    }

    /**
     * Handler for content filter.
     *
     * @param  string $content Existing content
     * @return string
     */
    public function append_button( $content )
    {
        if ( is_feed() )
            return $content;

        return $content . $this->button_form();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the button form or a feedback message after submit.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function button_form()
    {
        $this->load_translation();

        if ( 'POST' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] )
            return $this->get_form();

        return $this->handle_submit();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the form or an empty string.
     *
     * @uses apply_filters() 'RU_show_form' to suppress form output.
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_form()
    {
        global $post;

        if ( empty ( $post )
            or ! in_array( get_post_type( $post ), $this->post_types )
            // You may disable the form conditionally. For example: restrict it
            // to posts with post-format 'video'.
            or ! apply_filters( $this->prefix . '_show_form', TRUE, $post )
        )
            return '';

        $post_id      = (int) $post->ID;
        $url          = esc_attr( $this->current_url );
        $hidden       = $this->get_hidden_field();
        $nonce        = wp_create_nonce( __FILE__ );
        $button_text  = __( 'Request Update', 'plugin_RU' );

        $form = <<<RUFORM
    <form method='post' action='$url' class='{$this->prefix}_form'>
        <input type='hidden' name='{$this->prefix}[$this->nonce_name]' value='$nonce' />
        <input type='hidden' name='{$this->prefix}[post_id]' value='$post_id' />
        <input type='submit' name='{$this->prefix}[report]' value='$button_text' />
    </form>
    RUFORM;

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Hidden text field as spam protection.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function get_hidden_field()
    {
        // prevent doubled IDs if you use the_content() on archive pages.
        static $counter = 0;

        $field    = $this->hidden_field . "_$counter";
        $counter += 1;
        $title    = esc_attr__( 'Leave this empty', 'plugin_RU' );

        return "<style scoped>#$field{display:none}</style>
            <input name='{$this->prefix}[$field]' title='$title' />";
    }

    /**
     * Handle form submission.
     *
     * @uses apply_filters() 'RU_recipient' to set the mail recipient.
     *      'RU_from' to set the 'From' header.
     * @return string
     */
    private function handle_submit()
    {
        if ( ! isset ( $_POST[ $this->prefix ] )
            or '' == trim( implode( '', $_POST[ $this->prefix ] ) )
            or ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $this->prefix ][ $this->nonce_name ], __FILE__ )
            or ! empty ( $_POST[ $this->prefix ][ $this->hidden_field ] )
            or   empty ( $_POST[ $this->prefix ][ 'post_id' ] )
        )
            return $this->get_form();

        $blog_name = get_bloginfo( 'name' );

        // Pro tempore. You may add an option for this in 'wp-admin'.
        $recipient = get_option( 'admin_email' );
        $recipient = apply_filters( $this->prefix . '_recipient', $recipient );

        $subject   = sprintf(
            __( 'UPDATE REQUEST ON %s', 'plugin_RU' ),
            $blog_name
        );
        $message  = sprintf(
            __( "Please update the Plugin\Theme on:\n <%s>", 'plugin_RU' ),
            get_permalink( (int) $_POST[ $this->prefix ][ 'post_id' ] )
        );
        $from     = "From: [UPDATE REQUEST] $blog_name <$recipient>";
        $from     = apply_filters( $this->prefix . '_from', $from );
        $send     = wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $message, $from );

        $error    = __(
            'Sorry, we could not send the report. May we ask you to use the contact page instead?',
            'plugin_RU'
        );
        $success  = __( "Thank you! We will take a look and update is avaliable, please allow 48 Hours for all update requests.", 'plugin_RU' );
        $feedback = $send ? $success : $error;

        return "<p class='{$this->prefix}_result'>$feedback</p>";
    }

    /**
     * Load translation.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    private function load_translation()
    {
        return load_plugin_textdomain(
            'plugin_RU',
            FALSE,
            plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) . '/lang'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could this help you?  https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/ -> woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button <-

Comment: Thank you, I have seen that page, Im struggling to understand where I put the hook so it displays in the correct place at the moment it displays after the content.